# How to get a disk usage map on linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I would like to create a map of what files are written where on the hard drive.  It should output something like a directory tree, and for each file, a list of sectors ([10-20],[80-90],[60-70]) that come together to make up the entire file.
e.g. to create a visualization like the old school windows disk defragmenter:

[image: windows defrag]

Are there any tools available for this?

Comment: The standard tool on Debian derivations is `Disk Usage Analyser` (`baobab`). This won't show fragmentation, but for individual files (not directories) you can show the sectors it occupies using one of the tools described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106824). I don't know of a GUI tool.

Comment: "show the sectors it occupies"... For the purpose of creating my visualization, suppose I have a file that occupies a sector but doesn't occupy the entire sector, (e.g. a 8114 byte file written across two 4096 byte sectors); is it safe to assume that the first sector is fully occupied, the second sector has the first (8114 - 4096) bytes occupied, and the remaining (4096*2-8114) bytes of the second sector are "garbage", as opposed to some other file?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the case. I learned about filing systems in the 80s, when the OS was Unix, not Linux. I recall that, to save wasted space, one of the options for small files was to pack several into a physical sector, though I cannot now remember what constituted a small file (probably up to either 128 or 256 bytes), but they didn't use the free space of multi-sector files for small files. I don't know if modern extN file systems use a similar structure, but it would be a pity if they had lost it in Linux. Large files had a different structure again, allowing TB files even in the 80s!

Comment: The language you used in your comment helped me search!  Here's the answer to my commentquestion:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133149/can-multiple-files-be-stored-in-the-same-block

Comment: Interesting link. Back to your original question, most of what I've read suggests that fragmentation is not normally a problem on extN file systems, although my tests have found the odd file with fragments in the thousands. What I did was write a script which finds each file, counts the number of fragments in each, then sorts into a report in fragment count order: to make its size manageable, omit all unfragmented files. If this seems like a solution, I'll submit the script in an answer, since it's too complex for a comment.

Comment: I have also written a short script that performs a similar function.  You should absolutely answer the question with your script and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard tool on Debian derivations is `Disk Usage Analyser` (`baobab`), but this won't show fragmentation.

The only way I know of showing fragmentation is to use a command-line process on a file-by-file basis, using one of the tools described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106824).

To this end I wrote a script using `hdparm --fibmap`:-

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# frags MountPoint SkipFrags    Reports all files under MountPoint with more than SkipFrags fragments
#       MountPoint defaults to / (root file system)
#       SkipFrags  defaults to 1 (report all files with more than one fragment)
#                  (setting to 0 will report all files, including unfragmanted)
#
# The report is sorted in fragment count order and must be run as root 
#
[ "${1:0:1}" == "-" ] && \
    echo 'frags MountPoint SkipFrags    Reports all files under MountPoint with more than SkipFrags fragments' && \
    echo '      MountPoint defaults to / (root file system)' && \
    echo '      SkipFrags  defaults to 1 (report all files with more than one fragment)' && \
    echo '                 (setting to 0 will report all files, including unfragmanted)' && \
    echo 'The report is sorted in fragment count order and must be run as root' && \
    { return 1 2>/dev/null; exit 1; }
[ "$(whoami)" != "root" ] && { echo 'Must be run from "root"' >&2; return 13 2>/dev/null; exit 13; }
eof='***EOF***'    ; # End-of-file marker
{ find "$1"/ -mount -type f; echo "$eof"; } | \
    while read -r f; \
        do  [ "$f" == "$eof" ] && { echo -ne "\e[K" >&2; continue; }; \
            r=$(hdparm --fibmap "$f" | grep -E "^[ 0-9]+$" | wc -l); \
            [ $r -gt "${2:-1}" ] && { echo -ne "\e[K--- $r: ${f::$(($COLUMNS-${#r}-6))}\r" >&2; echo "$r: $f"; } \
        done | \
sort -nt :
```

Note that, although I've documented the script as scanning a whole disc from its mount point, you can get the sorted results for a specific directory, and I recommend doing this initially on a small directory to make sure that it gives sensible results.

The process is rather slow, and the sort means that you don't get any results until every file has been scanned, so I added a diagnostic on `stderr` as each file to be reported is found. The escape sequence is for `xterm` and relies on `$COLUMNS` being set by `shopt -s checkwinsize; export COLUMNS` in `~/.bashrc` (or another initialisation file). Avoiding line-feeds stops the script being slowed by scrolling.

I've used `[ ... ] &&` instead of `if [ ... ]; then` in order to reduce nesting and abbreviate the script. The `return 1 2>/dev/null; exit 1;` sequence is a trick I picked up to return an error code whether the script is called normally or from a `.`/`source` command.

Comment: I've just added an important parameter to the `find` command: `-mount` stops traversing other mounted file systems, which generates errors, especially on mounted network shares.

Comment: Further tests show that the script works fine on `/` and on other physical mounts, such as `/boot/efi`, but not on network shares nor on certain file system types, such as `tmpfs`. I don't know how to make it handle these, or at least give an error that the file system is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

I usually script in python, so if anyone is interested in a python version of AFH's answer.  Mine hinges on the `filefrag` command.  This walks through the directory tree starting at the cli argument `root`, and collects the filename, file size, and block extents.  It may be handy to add arguments to specify the block size and such if needed.

```
import subprocess
import os
import re
import argparse

size = re.compile("(\d+) \(\d+ block")

def get_extents(root):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for f in files:
            fullpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, f))
            output = subprocess.check_output(["filefrag", "-e", "-v", fullpath]).decode("utf-8")
            lines = output.splitlines()
            sizeline = lines[1]
            extentlines = lines[3:-1]
            print(fullpath)
            print("size in bytes:", size.search(sizeline).group(1))
            extents = []
            for extentline in extentlines:
                stuff = extentline.split()
                lower = stuff[3].strip(".")
                upper = stuff[4].strip(":")
                extents.append((lower, upper))
            print("extents:", extents)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("get the extents of all the files")
    parser.add_argument("root", type=os.path.expanduser, help="the root folder to examine recursively on")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    get_extents(args.root)
```